# multirow problem in table

Tags: tables, multirow

I wrote a code to produce a simple table and I use \multirow

I don't know why the output is like this: !

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{EFEFEF}

\begin{table}[H]
\small
\begin{tabular}{| p{0.05\linewidth} | p{0.3\linewidth} | p{0.1\linewidth} | p{0.1\linewidth} | p{0.1\linewidth} | p{0.2\linewidth} |}
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} 
\multicolumn{2}{|p{0.4\linewidth}|}{\textbf{BLA}} & \textbf{BLA} & \textbf{BLA} & \textbf{BLA} 
& \textbf{BLA}
\\ \hline 
1a & BLA
&  ++ & ++ &  ++ 
& BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA
\\ \hline 
1b & Informal notations 
&  ++ & + &  +
& \multirow{2}{1\linewidth}{BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA }
\\ \hline 
1c & BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA 
&  ++ & ++ &  ++
& 
\\ \hline 
1d & BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA
&  + & + &  +
& ANYTHING
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{\textbf{BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA}}
\label{Table:Table11}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Any help ?

Comment: What's the reason for `\multirow`? I see none.

Comment: 1b & 1c have the same row

Comment: You can use `makecell` if you don't want to use the `multirow` functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are after something like this:

[image]

(red lines shows page layout)

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem. In preamble it should load only packages relevant to your problem, document content let be limited to problem only.
- Your problem is simple to solve by use of `tabularray` package. Its multi row cells, itd syntax is `\SetCell[r=<number of spanned rows>˙] <cell content>`.
- An example of MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \small
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {c X[j] lll X[j]},
              row{1} = {font=\bfseries,bg=gray!30},
               vspan = even
             }
\SetCell[c=2]{l}    BLA 
    & BLA   & BLA   & BLA   & BLA   & BLA                       \\
%
1a  & BLA   &  ++   & ++    &  ++   & BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA   \\
1b  & Informal notations
            &  ++   & +     &  +    & \SetCell[r=2]{j}
                                    BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA 
                                    BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA 
                                    BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA 
                                    BLA BLA BLA                 \\
1c  & BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA
            &  ++   & ++    &  ++   &                           \\
1d  & BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA
            &  +    & +     &  +    & ANYTHING                  \\
\end{tblr}
    \caption{BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA}
    \label{Table:Table11}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

For more details how to use `tabularray` package, last version today is 2021P, see package documentation.

Answer (score 1):

First, you MWE is incomplete, so I had to make a few hypotheses. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{EFEFEF}

\begin{table}[H]
\small
\begin{tabular}{| p{0.05\linewidth} | p{0.3\linewidth} | p{0.1\linewidth} | p{0.1\linewidth} | p{0.1\linewidth} | p{0.2\linewidth} |}
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} 
\multicolumn{2}{|p{0.4\linewidth}|}{\textbf{BLA}} & \textbf{BLA} & \textbf{BLA} & \textbf{BLA} 
& \textbf{BLA}
\\ \hline 
1a & BLA
&  ++ & ++ &  ++ 
& BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA
\\ \hline 
1b & Informal notations 
&  ++ & + &  +
& \multirow{2}{1\linewidth}{BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA }
\\ \cline{1-5}
1c & BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA 
&  ++ & ++ &  ++
& \\
 & & & & & \\ 
 & & & & & \\ 
 & & & & & \\ 
 & & & & & \\ 
 & & & & & \\ \hline 
1d & BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA
&  + & + &  +
& ANYTHING
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{\textbf{BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA}}
\label{Table:Table11}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here is the relevant output:

[image: Output]

---

### Discussion:

There might be a way for the rows to adjust themselves vertically in multirows, but I think that's an other question.